# How to fetch all variants of a product from shopify graphql api?

Tags: node.js, graphql, shopify

I want to fetch all variants of a product suing shopify graphql api, but it seems like we have to define the number of variants or any other thing we want by using `first` argument after the query. I want to get all variants of the product instead of defining a number of variants, how can this be possible?

```js
const myproducts = await axios({
        url: `https://${req.session.shop}/admin/api/2022-01/graphql.json`,
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          "X-Shopify-Access-Token": req.session.token,
        },
        data: {
            query: `
                {
                  product(id: "gid://shopify/Product/6829796196490") {
                    title
                    variants(first: 5) {
                      edges {
                        cursor
                        node {
                          selectedOptions {
                            name
                            value
                          }
                          media(first: 5) {
                            edges {
                              node {
                                alt
                                mediaContentType
                                status
                                __typename
                                ... on MediaImage {
                                  id
                                  preview {
                                    image {
                                      originalSrc
                                    }
                                  }
                                  __typename
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }

                      pageInfo {
                        hasNextPage
                        
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
            `,
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A product can't have more than 100 variants, that is a set limit by Shopify.

So in order to get ALL variants you just have to say `first: 100` as long as your request cost doesn't exceed the allowed bucket cost for the query you will get them.

As for what you are asking, there is no way to get all variants without using `first` or `last`, this is a requirement when you are trying to get an array of edges.

Comment: but when I try to query only 25 products, I am getting rate limits and I am unable to figure out on how to do it effectively without getting rate limits, can you please help by showing an example with cursor and pagination of querying a large data without getting limits

Comment: Please help, I really need an example nodejs code for this

Comment: @JoelSmith if you want to get multiply products with all of their variants I don't think that GraphQL is the way to go. Better use Rest API instead, since there is no way to skip the rate limit without making multiply requests and waiting for each one of them to finish in order to fill your bucket size again.

Comment: In future I might need to use graphql to query all data instead of rest api, how would you do it without getting the rate limit error?

Comment: @JoelSmith I will combine GraphQL and Rest API. Rest API for the large request and GraphQL for small specific ones.

Comment: Like you said to use rest api for getting variants of a product id, so if there are 100 variants and we want to get them all, we can easily do it using rest api without caring about cost ?